# 1 byte can be the same with 2 bytes?

Tags: android, byte, packet

I program on Android with Java and I need to send an UDP/IP packet which is dynamic.

And I wondered if I send

```
byte[] array = { 0xDA, 0x54 };
```

would be the same with

```
byte[] array = { 0xDA54 };
```

Thank you

Comment: `0xDA54` is not a byte, so this would not be a valid `byte[]`.

Comment: Neither of those *compile*, so in that way they are the same. However, `0xDA54` cannot be stored in a byte, so no, **they are not the same**. If you store the `short` (or `int`) value `0xDA54` as two bytes, you may get `DA 54` or `54 DA`, depending on the [endian order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: Hi,  thank you for this fast answer. Actually, I have int entries and I would like to have byte[] in little endian. that's why I ask the question. 

Do you know a way to do that in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Both arrays are represented as:

> 1101 1010 0101 0100

Be careful though because the data will be different for each if you try to convert the values to/from network byte order.